# can we retrieve mobile contacts using ionic framework with ngcordova from browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

Is it possible to retrieve contacts from google chrome webbrowser from mobile?

Actually There is something wrong with ngCordova plugin in my local(May be some js file or something is not loaded correctly). 
Code is :

```
$cordovaContacts.pickContact().then(function (result) {
   $scope.selectedContact = result;
});
```

Error is: 
 
 **Cannot call method 'pickContact' of undefined** 
 
Exactly in this code its giving the above error:
**navigator.contacts.pickContact(function (contact)....**
So I want to debug what is wrong with that. So I kept alert prompts with try-catch blocks, But those are not thats much usefull. 
So from the app I'm not able debug properly with alert statements. 
 **So first question: Is there any good way to debug the app?**

So due to this, I moved on to web browser. I'm running ionic app using "ionic serve" and accessing the app from my mobile browser. This is working fine. But before proceeding further, I want to confirm that, 
 **Is it possible to get the mobile contacts from the web browser using ngCordova api?**

Comment: I have not developed for Cordova in a long time but it seems that property is only set when you are actually running in a Cordova/Phonegap environment, not in the browser. You may need something like http://emulate.phonegap.com/ if you don't have a phone to test in.

Comment: What about this plugin
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngCordova is an API to communicate with Cordova.  It has a lot of different plugins to perform functions on a mobile device.  Those plugins are installed during the build process of the iOS or android package and not part of your angular project.  You cannot access those plugins from a normal browser.